# How to configure MongoDB for REST?

Tags: java, database, mongodb, configuration, non-relational-database

I wanted to configure MongoDB 6.x for rest. Now Ive read that you need to use directives. I tried to configure it with https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/expansion-directives/#std-label-expansion-directives.

I have the following configuration:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

#start
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write  logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 28017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
__rest: "http://mongoconf.example.net:28017/test"
type: "string"
trim: "whitespace"
digest: "<string>"
digest_key: "<string>"`
```

Now I get the following error message: digest: "Not a valid, even length hex string"

Tried the configuration described "Expansion Directives Reference" at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/expansion-directives/#std-label-expansion-directives

Comment: What is the response when you call the REST with another tool, e.g. postman?

Comment: There is no response because I cannot connect to mongodb via MongoDBCompass. MongoDBCompass response with "connection refused". If I look up if the port is already in use, it shows me that it isn't. I also can't connect with java spring to the database because the exception "adress already in use" appears...

Comment: I got a connection at port 28017(previsiously httpinterface) but I cant request over postman. I got the following error message: "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port."

Comment: You cannot use MongoDB with REST interace, MongoDB has no web interface. `__rest` supports loading specific values in the configuration file or loading the entire configuration file. It does not provide a REST/HTML service for the MongoDB.

Comment: Did you include the `--configExpand "rest"` option? And did you have a look at example https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/expansion-directives/#output-the-configuration-file-with-resolved-expansion-directive-values - should make it more clear.

Comment: That means even if I wrote an Rest Controller in Spring for MongoDB I cant do rest request becaues it is not supported in newer versions of mongodb?

Comment: I have the feeling you misunderstand the REST directive. You can configure the MongoDB dynamically (i.e. get values from REST response instead of written in text file). You cannot access the Mongo database via REST.

Comment: You wrote "You cannot access the Mongo database via REST." Does that mean that you cannot create a REST API with java spring and mongodb? I just want to write a RestController for MongoDB and access data via postman. Is that possible or not?

Comment: Of course, you can write an application which provides a REST serrvice and connects to MongoDB. But you cannot access a MongoDB via REST directly.